# Marker recognition from image in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I would like to know if there's any library for PHP which recognises simple markers from an image (like a black square or a red circle).
The idea is to scan a paper with an specific template and crop and export some areas by detecting this markers.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to use the PHP ImageMagick library known as Imagick (this isn't installed by default)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php

They discuss 'Circle Detection here

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=17204

And recommend a method of edge detection using the convolve filter

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/convolve/#edgedet

Comment: And any library made in pure PHP without needing to use ImageMagick?